# Excel: If statement true grab value from cell beside it

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a lot of data that is paired in Excel. Is there a way I can use the `IF`/`IFS` statement and `MATCH` in order to compare date and if it matches, copy the data in the column beside it.

[image: Example:]

If the value in Data Row A equals Table 1 Row X, set Results Row A = Table 2 Row X

I can't just do a nested `IF`/`IFS` statement as the data is over 200 rows, which would be a massive `IF` statement.

Answer (score 1):

[XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) will solve it. The best is if you'll look in the official office's support page [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) (it actually has a great short video that demonstrates the use of this function).

If you're using an Excel version that doesn't support XLOOKUP, I'll suggest using [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

If all fails (for example - VLOOKUP assumes the search column is the first column, but you want to get a row based on values on the 2nd column) - use [INDEX & MATCH](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5NMg9ONd84).

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample, I agree with shemadolev, Vlookup and Xlookup may be helpful.

[image]

Enter `=IFNA(XLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$A$11,$B$2:$B$11),"")` or `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$B$11,2,0),"")` in D2, and pull down.